# maximum recursion depth exceeded during minmaxscalar

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have my dataset defined in base_df, am performing MinMaxScalar

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
def MinMaxScaler(base_df):
    le=MinMaxScaler()
    le.fit(base_df)
    x=le.transform(base_df)
    dat1=pd.DataFrame(x)
    dat1.columns=base_df.columns
    base_df=data1
    return base_df
```

and returning the function as below

```
MinMaxScaler(base_df)
```

But am facing this error

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

what is the possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the custom function name - `MinMaxScaler`

Notice, that `sklearn` package *has* a `MinMaxScaler` function out of the box, which is conflicting with the name that you have for your custom function.

**Fix**

Rename your function to something else -

Change `def MinMaxScaler(base_df):` to something like `def MinMaxScalerCustom(base_df):`

Call it accordingly - `MinMaxScalerCustom(base_df)`

This will resolve it.

**Full Code**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
def MinMaxScalerCustom(base_df):
    le=MinMaxScaler()
    le.fit(base_df)
    x=le.transform(base_df)
    dat1=pd.DataFrame(x)
    dat1.columns=base_df.columns
    base_df=data1
    return base_df
```

Call it

```
MinMaxScalerCustom(base_df)
```